# Upload image, resize it, rename it and move it to a directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image, resize it, rename it and move it to a directory, but something goes wrong. After I resize and rename the file I can't move it to a directory. I can only move the original or just renamed not resized file to a directory.

This is my code:

```
$file=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size=$_FILES['file']['size'];

switch(strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']))
{
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    default:
        exit('Unsupported type: '.$_FILES['file']['type']);
}
$max_width = 194;
$max_height = 160;

// Get current dimensions
$old_width  = imagesx($image);
$old_height = imagesy($image);

// Calculate the scaling we need to do to fit the image inside our frame
$scale      = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);

// Get the new dimensions
$new_width  = ceil($scale*$old_width);
$new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);
// Create new empty image
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

// Resize old image into new
imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 
    $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($new, NULL, 90);
$data = ob_get_clean();
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($new);

$file1 = explode(".", $data);
$newfilename = "product_".$r . $file1;

$upload_path1="../upload/items/".basename($newfilename);
if(file_exists($upload_path1)){
echo '<div class="redalert">already exist</div>'; 
} else { 
$upload=move_uploaded_file($data,$upload_path1); 
}
```

Comment: move_uploaded_file expects a tmp file, and you are feeding it the raw data, I would try file_put_contents instead.
edit: you can use 2nd argument in imagejpg to save the image to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjaco has already said the corrected solution. But it will still not work because you exploded the raw data and used the resulting array as the filename. File name here should be string. There is an undefined variable `$r` as well.

So the correct solution would be:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newfilename = "product".md5(uniqid("") . time()).'.'.$ext;//to make file name unique
file_put_contents('upload/items/'.$newfilename, $data);
```

Comment: The veriable $r is the unique number that i put after product, so it become like "product_1, product_2" etc...
With "file_put_contents" it work, it does move the file, but now it's not resize as i define it with "$max_width = 194; $max_height = 160;", the image that was moved to the directory become "Width - 120, height - 160"...

Comment: @tyrlaka, check it with 305×335 image size and it becomes 148*160. If you want 194 as the maximum width, then change `min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);` to `max($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);`